# Delete blob inside virtual directory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to delete a blob inside a virtual directory, with no luck. A 404 error is always returned.

File url is something like this: https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/YY/pdf/pdf/file.pdf
where XXX is my storage account and YY is a container.

I've tried to delete trhough it's full name (pdf/pdf/file.pdf, no luck.

```
blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("pdf/pdf/file.pdf"); //or
blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("file.pdf");
```

Also, tried to navigate trhough virtual folders (GetDirectoryReference) and delete file when I get to it, no luck also.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("YY");

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob;

string sBlob = fullUrl.Substring(fullUrl.IndexOf("YY/") + ("YY/").Length);

string[] sDirs = sBlob.Split(new Char[] { '/' });

if (sDirs.Length > 0)
{
     CloudBlobDirectory dir = container.GetDirectoryReference(sDirs[0]);
     if (sDirs.Length > 2) 
     { 
          for (int i = 1; i < sDirs.Length - 2; i++)
          {
               dir = dir.GetDirectoryReference(sDirs[i]);
          }
     }
     blockBlob = dir.GetBlockBlobReference(sDirs[sDirs.Length - 1]);
}
else
{
     blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(sBlob);
}

blockBlob.Delete(); //when debugging, I can see blockBlob properties here
```

Note: I can sucessfully delete files in the root (https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/YY/file.pdf).

Error:

```
blockBlob.Delete()' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException'
    base: {"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not found."}
    RequestInformation: {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.RequestResult}
```

**UPDATE:**

I managed to delete using this code:

```
foreach (var blobItem in container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true)) {
   if (blobItem.Uri.ToString() == caminho) {
      blockBlob.Delete();
      return "";
   }
}
```

...but it seems an insane solution... :/

Comment: can you check and paste here the exact error returned from the Storage Service?

Comment: @astaykov I've just updated original post... thanks

Comment: Are you 100% sure that this blob still exists? Does it throw exception when you use `GetBlobReferenceFromServer`

Comment: @plentysmart just tried blockBlob = (CloudBlockBlob)blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(blockBlob.Uri); and, effectively, I get 404 error. But in WA management portal, I can see this blob, and its uri is exactly the same!

Comment: Can you see your blob when you list blobs  -  `container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);` ?

Comment: Yes, I can. I even used a TreeView to list hierarchically all contents (account->containers->folders->subfolders->(...)->files)

Comment: which version of SDK you are working with? More important is the version Azure StorageClient library.

Comment: SDK: 2.4
Azure StorageClient: 4.3.0.0 (runtime version: v4.0.30319)
Funny is that there are 3 blobs there that enter  "if (blobItem.Uri.ToString() == caminho)" but returns an error when deleting. It can list, but cannot delete... :/

Comment: wired ... very strange